# В каких переменных хранятся данные?

Tags: html, php

`input type="checkbox"` - (нужно принять информацию из 2х полей). Допустим, у нас есть форма:

```
<form name="search" action="search.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="tema" value="все" checked="checked" /> Все<br /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="tema" value="новости" /> Новости<br /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="tema" value="товары" /> Товары<br /> 
<input type="submit" value="OK" />
</form>
```

Если пользователь поставит галочки на "новости" **и** на "товары", то где будет храниться о первой выбранной позиции, а где о второй?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В случае с PHP вам нужно оформлять использование checkbox следующим образом:

```
...
<input type="checkbox" name="tema[]" value="все" checked="checked" /> Все<br /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="tema[]" value="новости" /> Новости<br /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="tema[]" value="товары" /> Товары<br />
...
```

Тогда в своей программе вы сможете обработать эти параметры следующим образом:

```
<?php
# Файл search.php
if (!empty($_POST["tema"])) {
    foreach ($_POST["tema"] as $value) {
        echo "Получено значание: $value<br />";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Нужно задавать разные `name`. Если все будут однаковыми, то в search.php передастся только последнее значение. Или, как написал [[@chernomyrdin](/users/3261/chernomyrdin)](/users/3261/chernomyrdin) оформлять их как элемент массива `name="value[]"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
name="tema[]"
```

использование квадратных скобок в названиях аттрибутах дает невалидный HTML, и если это критично, то лучше этим не пользоваться.
В вашем случае проще назвать эти чекбоксы по разному и в php далее проверять наличие этих переменных в POST, пр.

```
html ... <input type="checkbox" name="news" value="новости" /> Новости<br />...

php ... $tema = (array_key_exists('news', $_POST)) ? $_POST['news'] : false; ...
```

Если неприменно нужно использовать значение только одной переменной, то вполне можно заменить элементы `checkbox` на элемент формы `select`, тогда и овцы целы и волки веселые -

```
html ... <form name="search" action="search.php" method="post">
  <select name="tema">
    <item value="все">все</item>
      <item value="новости">Новости</item>
      <item value="товары">Товары</item>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="OK" />
</form> ...

php ... $tema = $_POST['tema'];...
```

возможность добавления множественного выбора выполняется применением атрибута `multiple="multiple"` тэгу `select`, хотя в вашем случае не вижу смысла

Answer (score 0):

Если принятие информации делается с помощью JavaScript (ajax), актуально использование соответствующих id (class) для каждого элемента. Получить конкретное значение вы сможете через getElementById или $('#id') ($(".class")), если используете jquery.